# Heroku : FFMpeg installed but php worker can't find it

Tags: php, symfony, heroku, ffmpeg, symfony-messenger

### Context

I've a RabbitMQ's queue that contains AMQPMessage, those messages are referencing a video that needs to be treated (cut essentially and encoded in x264 also)

Here's the code that cause the issue (pretty straightforward)

```
        $ffprobe = FFProbe::create([
            'ffmpeg.binaries'  => '/usr/bin/ffmpeg',
            'ffprobe.binaries' => '/usr/bin/ffprobe',
        ]);
```

### Error Message

TL;DR :
`Error: "Unable to load FFProbe"`

> [2019-12-03 14:55:07] messenger.ERROR: Error thrown while handling message App\Api\Message\AMQPvideoFFMPEG. Sending for retry #1 using 1000 ms delay. Error: "Unable to load FFProbe" {"message":"[object] (App\Api\Message\AMQPvideoFFMPEG: {})","class":"App\Api\Message\AMQPvideoFFMPEG","retryCount":1,"delay":1000,"error":"Unable to load FFProbe","exception":"[object] (Symfony\Component\Messenger\Exception\HandlerFailedException(code: 0): Unable to load FFProbe at /app/vendor/symfony/messenger/Middleware/HandleMessageMiddleware.php:80, FFMpeg\Exception\ExecutableNotFoundException(code: 0): Unable to load FFProbe at /app/vendor/php-ffmpeg/php-ffmpeg/src/FFMpeg/Driver/FFProbeDriver.php:50, Alchemy\BinaryDriver\Exception\ExecutableNotFoundException(code: 0): Executable not found, proposed : /usr/bin/ffprobe at /app/vendor/alchemy/binary-driver/src/Alchemy/BinaryDriver/AbstractBinary.php:160)"} []

### Configuration & tests

On Heroku I've 2 dynos :

```
- web $(composer config bin-dir)/heroku-php-nginx -C config/packages/dev/heroku_nginx.conf public/
- worker php bin/console messenger:consume ffmpeg
```

On this platform, I've also 3 buildpacks, look below, with this specific [buildpack](https://github.com/foxtrapplimited/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg) :

[image: with a custom buildpack for ffmpeg]

To make sure that all is available here's the results of my checks :

```
 heroku run "ffmpeg -version" -a project-dev 
Running ffmpeg -version on ⬢ project-dev... up, run.6134 (Hobby)
ffmpeg version N-67574-g9d6ad68 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
built on Nov 12 2014 11:35:09 with gcc 4.4.3 (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1)
configuration: --enable-static --disable-shared --disable-asm --extra-libs=-L/app/vendor/libs/lib --extra-cflags=-I/app/vendor/libs/include --prefix=/app/vendor/ffmpeg --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-nonfree --enable-libx264 --enable-gpl
libavutil      54. 11.100 / 54. 11.100
libavcodec     56. 12.100 / 56. 12.100
libavformat    56. 12.103 / 56. 12.103
libavdevice    56.  2.100 / 56.  2.100
libavfilter     5.  2.103 /  5.  2.103
libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
```

```
 heroku run "ffprobe -version" -a projet-dev
Running ffprobe -version on ⬢ projet-dev... up, run.2357 (Hobby)
ffprobe version N-67574-g9d6ad68 Copyright (c) 2007-2014 the FFmpeg developers
built on Nov 12 2014 11:35:09 with gcc 4.4.3 (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1)
configuration: --enable-static --disable-shared --disable-asm --extra-libs=-L/app/vendor/libs/lib --extra-cflags=-I/app/vendor/libs/include --prefix=/app/vendor/ffmpeg --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-nonfree --enable-libx264 --enable-gpl
libavutil      54. 11.100 / 54. 11.100
libavcodec     56. 12.100 / 56. 12.100
libavformat    56. 12.103 / 56. 12.103
libavdevice    56.  2.100 / 56.  2.100
libavfilter     5.  2.103 /  5.  2.103
libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
```

All good !

### Disclaimer

This code is working well on another platform (handled by kubernetes), so it may need some adjustments with heroku. But can't find it.

**Why this error since my configuration is not showing any missconfigurations? What am I missing here?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change to:

```
    $ffprobe = FFProbe::create([
        'ffmpeg.binaries'  => '/app/vendor/ffmpeg_bundle/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg',
        'ffprobe.binaries' => '/app/vendor/ffmpeg_bundle/ffmpeg/bin/ffprobe',
    ]);
```

You were using `/usr/bin/`, but your files were not located there.

- The script edited your `PATH` to include `$HOME/vendor/ffmpeg_bundle/ffmpeg/bin` and `--prefix` is set to `/app/vendor/ffmpeg`, so I suspect this is the location of the files.
- Run `whereis ffmpeg`. If `ffmpeg` is in your `PATH` it will give you the location.
- Why use ffmpeg from 2014? Development is very active so you're missing out on thousands of updates. Also, I recommend avoiding compiling without `--disable-asm` if possible (same for x264).

Comment: Hey thank you, are you sure about vendor ? You've right on heroku building logs, I saw that ffmpeg installed on another location, but it's not in vendors I'll test both paths, and come back to you thanks for your help

Comment: @GrecoJonathan Not sure because it is an informed guess, but it should be easy enough to verify.

Comment: on heroku it show only ffmpeg_module/...
on this link https://github.com/foxtrapplimited/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg/blob/master/bin/compile we have the full path but I'm in doubt of what I should put in the code you pointed

Comment: And you right about the buildpack version I will use another buildpack with the latest build, I just need to fix the path thing first

Comment: @GrecoJonathan I know nothing of heroku or buildpacks. I was simply looking at your ffmpeg configuration. The script is adding `$HOME/vendor/ffmpeg_bundle/ffmpeg/bin:$HOME/vendor/ffmpeg_bundle/libs/bin` to your `PATH` so you can look in those two directories for the executables. Or run `whereis ffmpeg`. You're just going to have to look around. Since it messed with your `PATH` you may just try `'ffmpeg.binaries'  => 'ffmpeg',`

Comment: Really thanks for all of your comments and help indeed whereis showed me that the realpath of my ffmpeg installation was here :  /app/vendor/ffmpeg_bundle/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg Good guess, thanks

Comment: On your Heroku Dashboard, you can go to More -> Run console and then running `which ffmpeg` and `which ffprobe` you can see the installation path :)